# Geoserver: Call custom OWS function from inside SLD

Tags: geoserver, sld

I've a PostGIS table published  as a layer, I need to style this layer using SLD. 
I need to call a custom OWS function (which I wrote) from inside the SLD. It should look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>test_fn_call</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>dark yellow square point style</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>dark yellow point</Title>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#99cc00</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
              </Mark>
              <Size>
              <ogc:Function name="gs:calcSize">
                <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                    <!-- **** What should I write here? **** -->
                </ogc:Function>
              </ogc:Function>
              </Size>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

calcSize is a function to calculate point size depending on some calculations on the feature's fields.

My question is what should I write as a parameter of this function, actually I need to path the current feature as a parameter, so what should I write in the SLD as a parameter?

Also in the java side, what should the parameter type be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SLD you need to name the properties being passed into the function as is shown in [this example](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function.html#sld-formatting).

In the function itself you need to specify the parameter types you expect and then you receive a list of `Parameters` that it is up to your code to extract and check. See the [function tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/function.html) for more detail.

```
public class SnapFunction implements Function {

    static FunctionName NAME = new FunctionNameImpl("snap", Point.class,
            FunctionNameImpl.parameter("point",Point.class),
            FunctionNameImpl.parameter("line",Geometry.class));

    private final List<Expression> parameters;

    private final Literal fallback;

    public SnapFunction(List<Expression> parameters, Literal fallback) {
        if (parameters == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("parameters required");
        }
```